# Topology of a sphere meeting the corner of a surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

[image: view oriented to the sphere]

[image: side view]

I need help with the topology of this object. It's a sphere merged into an angled surface. It's not quite a 45 degree angle, either, technically it's 41.99 degrees (10mm up, 9mm across)

Aaand, I forgot to actually add what my issue is. Basically, with subdivision on, the sphere is completely distorted. The top section is mostly alright, apart from the pole, but the "overhanging" section on the top face isn't even close to sphericall. I think the biggest issue is the angle makes it very hard to turn into quads. I've tried using a quad-sphere instead of a UV one, but since more than half of the sphere is inside the mesh, there isn't a clean line to split it at. (Also, ignore the ngon on the top face, that will be attached in the end, but given these issues with the topology, I didn't know how many verts I'd end up having on the top, so I haven't added the edge loops there yet. The bevelled edge you can see around the sphere is stopping any issues with that for now.

Comment: Honestly that's pretty good. The one thing I'd do is connect the last two vertices of the sphere in the top image to somewhere. I'm not at my pc so I can't show what I mean. Do you have other concerns with the topology?

Comment: Can you add some detail to this question to explain what help you need?  The only issue I see is the minor one that the two front sloping faces are now N-gons, and that's remedied easily by inseting the faces.

Comment: Added the details.